# Ajax Form Not Doing Anything

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form using Ajax that is suppose to show an error to the user when something is incorrect when the login. When I click the submit button nothing happens. I hate asking Stack overflow but you got to do what you got to do. And yes, I have Apache configured to not need file extensions.
This is the tutorial I am following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7Sn-f36TGM

Login Script:

```
    require("dbh.php");

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

    $errorEmpty = false;
    $errorEmail = false;
    $errorWrong = false;

    if(empty($email) || empty($pwd)) {
      echo "<p class='loginText'>Please Enter an Email Address and Password!</p>";
      $errorEmpty = true;
    } else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      echo "<p class='loginText'>Please Enter a Valid Email Address!</p>";
      $errorEmail = true;
    } else {
      echo "Success!";
    }
    } else {
      echo "<p class='loginText'>An Error Occurred!</p>"
    }
    header("/login?test");
```

loginForm.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#loginFormInput").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var email = $("#emailLogin").val();
    var pwd = $("#pwdLogin").val();
    $(".errorText").load("../php-scripts/login", {
      email: email,
      pwd: pwd
    });
  });
});
```

HTML Form:

```
<p class="errorText"></p>
<form action="../php-scripts/login.php" method="post" id="loginFormInput">
    <input type="text" name="email" class="textInput" id="emailLogin" placeholder="Email" maxlength="512"> <br>
    <input type="password" name="pwd" class="textInput" id="pwdLogin" placeholder="Password" maxlength="1024"> <br>
    <p class="rememberText">Remember Me:</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" class="rememberBox"> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" class="submitInput" title="Login">
  </form>
```

Comment: If you've open your `browser` and check the `console` tab, does it log a certain message?

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included jQuery properly? Are there any errors in the console? Are you storing plain text passwords?

Comment: What is `header("/login?test");` supposed to do? If you meant `header("Location: /login?test");`, why would you do that in a script that's being run from AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP code is doing `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`, but when you do the AJAX submission you don't provide a `submit` parameter. You need to add that to the parameters:

```
$(".errorText").load("../php-scripts/login", {
  email: email,
  pwd: pwd,
  submit: 'Login'
});
```

Or you could remove that check from the PHP, if that script is only used to process the AJAX requests.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing an element with class name `errorText`

Try adding a `<div class="errorText"></div>` somewhere